# Invoke Method in WorkFlow expecting Optional Parameters to be passed?

Tags: asp.net, workflow-foundation

I have method in Business Layer, which contains some optional parameters.
When I am trying to invoke the method from the WorkFlow 4.0, it is expecting me to pass
the optional parameters also.
Is there a way that I can avoid passing optional parameters to the method.

The method that I have is SendEmail(string emailTo, string domain, string smtpAdress = "POP");
When I call this method any where in the code.. I am just calling the method like
SendEmail("xx.com","PFE"), which is working fine

But in the Workflow..it gives a compilation error saying that 
" 'BLEmail' does not have a public instance method named 'SendEmail' matching the parameter types, generic type arguments, and generic type constraints supplied to InvokeMethod 'InvokeMethod'."

When I am passing the optional parameter, it works fine..but it loses the whole concept of optional parameter.

Please help..

Thanks and appreciate your feedback.

Sam.

Answer (score 0):

InvokeMethodActivity does not handle optional parameters. You have to provide all parameters regardless if they are optional or not.